# Build modifier - Bake object or Halt animation

Tags: animation, modifiers, baking

Is there a method of baking an object so it holds it's current state? For example at frame 60 (60% built) on the time line the object is what I would like to hold for re-animating. The actual build animation isn't what I want to use, just the partial built object.

Blender File:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W5UjPl-24Ho0Gd4wxwidY_-t9vbVhp-n

Comment: Either apply the modifier or keyframe the build percentage at a fixed value

Comment: Applying the build modifier seems to make the object disappear completely and key frames dont seem to hold the object at the desired shape. The only options it gives me are the: Start frame, Length of frames to 100% and seed.